# How do I find the value of the last character of a string for each string in a list>

Tags: scala, list, filter, foreach

I need to filter a List[String] based on a condition. Each String in the list ends with a number and I need to filter this list so that the new list only contains the strings which end with a number greater than 5. I have taken many approaches to this problem, this is the closest I could get to getting it to work but it tells me that there is a type mismatch.

```
val filteredList = lines.filter(lines.foreach(lines(_).takeRight(1).toInt) > 5)
```

"lines" is the list of strings I am trying to filter.

So if I passed in a list:

```
List("word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 6", "word 7", "word 8")
```

Then the expected output would be:

```
List("word 6", "word 7", "word 8")
```

Comment: always provide test data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here a possible solution:

I extended your test data to have bad data as well:

```
val lines = List("word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 6", "word 7", "word 8", "", "bad")
```

The filter algorithm uses *Pattern Matching*, where there are 2 cases.

```
val filteredList = 
    lines.map(_.reverse.toList)
    .filter{
      case x::_ if Character.isDigit(x) => x.asDigit > 5
      case _ => false
    }.map(_.mkString.reverse)
```

I reverse the String and change it to a List, so Pattern Matching is easier. In the last line I redo this again.

If you are absolutely sure that **your data is always in the expected form** it is a one liner:

```
lines.filter(_.last.asDigit > 5)
```

Ok with bad data you can also try to change the last character to a digit. In case there is none, it fails and you return false.

Be aware that some people think, you should not use exception handling to control the flow.

```
lines.filter(str =>
  Try(str.last.asDigit > 5).getOrElse(false)  
)
```

And here the version of *Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez*:

```
lines.filter(line => 
   line.lastOption.collect { 
     case char if (char.isDigit) => 
       char.asDigit 
     }.fold(_ > 5)(ifEmpty = false)
)
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez why not add it as an answer - it is hard to compare in a comment. Most people have problems understanding `collect` and `fold` - it took me also some time;).